# Choosing what to do in StackEgg doesn't persist the UI if returning within the round

Tags: bug, stackegg

To reproduce,

Decide what to do during a StackEgg round (click one of the buttons). Your choice is highlighted.

If you close the StackEgg dialog box / popup then click the advert to open it again still within the round's timer your choice is still in play in the current round but the UI doesn't reflect that you've made your choice.

Comment: So... [tag:status-norepro] in a day or two?